# How i can get return value in function inside function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my code:

```
exports.generate_qr = function(value) {
  var urlQR;
  QRCode.toDataURL(value, { scale: 10, errorCorrectionLevel: 'M' }, function (err, url) {
    urlQR = url;
  });
  return urlQR;
};
```

Then i call with

```
var url = exports.generate_qr("Hello World!");
console.log(url);
```

But only return **undefined**

Comment: why don't you return inside the QRCode.toDataURL function...

Comment: you can do it via callback function.